# Where should `.svn` be when checking out one dir from a repo?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The projects (ABC, DEF, ..) are organized in one SVN repository.

```
Repo ------ABC
     +-----DEF
     +-----GHI
     +-----JKL
```

In an attempt to avoid checking out the entire (vast) repository, I checked out (through TortoiseSVN) just the two projects that I am working on, DEF and JKL.

Update/commit cycles work fine for both, but I am puzzled by the different location of the `.svn` file.

```
myproj ------dir1------DEF+-----file1.c
                          +-----file2.c
                          +-----.svn
       +-----dir2+-----.svn
                 +-----JKL+-----file3.c
                          +-----file4.c
```

Where should `.svn` be when checking out one dir from a repo? If both locations are correct, what is the significance of the different structures?

**Update**

I should mention that these are two entirely distinct projects, with entirely different teams of collaborators, with entirely independent update/commit cycles.  I am not certain that it is wise to use the save SVN repo for multiple projects in this fashion.

**Update 2**

Even though I want to update/commit independently in each of these two projects, I do want to see the name of the project (DEF, ..) in my working directory after checkout. This gives me a mild confirmation that I am in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created `dir1`, then inside created `DEF`, then on it checked out `DEF` (by its path `Repo/DEF`). You also created `dir2`, then on it checked out `Repo` (by its path `Repo`), but chose only `JKL` in it, in what's called a sparse working copy (you clicked on a button "Choose items...", and in additional window selected only JKL folder and deselected all the rest).

Had you created `JKL` in `dir2` and checked out `JKL` on it (by its path `Repo/JKL`), then .svn folder would be inside `JKL`.

Comment: So you're saying that DEF is correct; the `.svn` file should be inside the (sub-) project directory, and that JKL is incorrect; the `.svn` file should not be at the same level as the (sub-) project directory; is that right?

Comment: @Vrokipal Well, in essence both are incorrect, because if you want to change the code in both folders and commit it you would have to commit it in two separate operations. But in order to have a single commit ability for your current directory structure you would have to create another repository (or new folder somewhere in current repository), and add DEF and JKL as something called "externals" to it.

Comment: If current directory structure (with `dir1` and `dir2`) is not important and you can live with directory structure where DEF and JKL are next to each other in the same folder, then you could check out from `Repo` path, and use sparse checkout to select only those two.

Comment: While committing to multiple externals at the same time is not usually possible TortoiseSVN has a smart piece of code that actually does it, if all externals belong to the same repository.

Comment: My third comment should stand between the first two, as it adds more info to "externals" idea.

Answer (score 0):

- `.svn` belongs to **working copy** root¹. Repository structure doesn't matter because a working copy can point to any folder within the repo.
- The name of the directory that holds a working copy is whatever you choose. You can even rename it and nothing will break in Subversion.

¹ <sub>Well, almost. If you check out a working copy with an [external](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) folder, you'll get another `.svn` directory in the external root, maybe deepe inside the outer working copy.</sub>

If all project layouts are identical, you didn't perform both check-outs the same way:

- For `DEF` you have a working copy at `/myproj/dir1/DEF/` that points to `file:///Repo/DEF`.
- For `JKL` you have a working copy at `/myproj/dir2` that points to `file:///Repo/` that only includes `file:///Repo/JKL` and excludes its siblings.

IMHO this is confusing and most likely an involuntary mistake. But, I insist, the layout of your working copies does not need to match the layout of your repository.

Comment: So you're saying that either of the two options is all right. It's simply a matter of where we define the "working copy root" to be. In one case it's `myproj`, and in the other it's `myproj/subdir`. No harm either way, and any of the identifiers (myproj, myproj or subdir) can also be changed with no harm. Is that right?

Comment: Your working copies are one level up. Please let me know if my updated answer solves your questions. All folders up to `/myproj/dir1/DEF/` and `/myproj/dir2` can be safely renamed.